# Reading aligned column data with fread

Tags: r, data.table

I came across a file like this:

```
COL1        COL2          COL3
weqw        asrg          qerhqetjw
weweg       ethweth       rqerhwrtjw
rhqerhqerhq qergqer       qerhqew5h
qerh        qergqer       wetjwryerj
```

I could not load it directly with `fread` so I replaced `\s+` by `,` with `sed` than I gave to fread and it solved it. But is there a built in way of reading this kind of data with `data.table` ?

Comment: How about `df <- read.table('test.dat',header=T)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fread` does not (yet) have any capabilities for reading [fixed-width files](http://www.softinterface.com/Convert-XLS/Features/Fixed-Width-Text-File-Definition.htm).

I, too, often come across files annoyingly stored like this. Feel free to add a feature request on the [Github page](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table).

It may not be so in your case, but your solution with `sed` would not work on a lot of FWF I come across because there's no space between columns, e.g. you'll see strings like 00010 that actually comprise 3 fields.

If that's the case, you'll need a field width dictionary, at which point you have several options:

1. [`read.fwf`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.fwf.html) within `R`
2. Write a `fwf`->`csv` program (I use one I wrote in `Python` and it's pretty fast, could share the code if you'd like)--basically the beefed up version of your initial approach, so that you never have to deal with the FWF again
3. Open it in Excel / LibreOffice / etc; there's a native FWF reader that tries (usually poorly) to guess the widths of the columns, which at least does half the work of specifying the column widths for you. Then you can save it as .csv or whatever from there.

I personally stick with the second option most often. `read.fwf` is not optimized like `fread` so it will probably be slow. And if you've got a lot (say 20+) of FWF to read, the 3rd option is pretty tedious.

But I agree it would be nice to have something like this built in to `fread`.

Comment: (a slightly bloated version of) the code can be found in this [repository of mine](https://github.com/MichaelChirico/wisconsin_teachers); it's nothing particularly novel, I dont think...

Comment: @statquant, `read_fwf` from the "readr" package would be much faster than base R's `read.fwf` (though won't be able to touch `fread`s speed).

Comment: @AnandaMahto thanks for the heads up! tool belt version upgrade B-)

Answer (score 1):

Fixed in current devel (v1.9.5) recently. Please upgrade and test (and report if any issues).

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.5+
fread("~/Downloads/tmp.txt")
#           COL1    COL2       COL3
# 1:        weqw    asrg  qerhqetjw
# 2:       weweg ethweth rqerhwrtjw
# 3: rhqerhqerhq qergqer  qerhqew5h
# 4:        qerh qergqer wetjwryerj
```

`fread()` gained `strip.white` argument (default=`TRUE`) amidst other arguments. Please check `README` on project page for up-to-date NEWS.