# R: Reading file with multiple white spaces as delimiter + white space as missing value

Tags: r, whitespace, read.table

I've got a problem similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16979858/reading-text-file-with-multiple-space-as-delimiter-in-r), but in my case the file has also white space as missing value.

I'm working with the meteorological sounding data set from the University of Wyoming, you can find an example [here](http://weather.uwyo.edu/cgi-bin/sounding?region=samer&TYPE=TEXT:LIST&YEAR=2016&MONTH=02&FROM=1212&TO=1212&STNM=83746)

What I've tried to do so far:

```
data = read.table("http://weather.uwyo.edu/cgi-bin/sounding?region=samer&TYPE=TEXT:LIST&YEAR=2016&MONTH=02&FROM=1212&TO=1212&STNM=83746",skip=10,nrows=100,fill=T,sep="")
```

It works fine, apart from the last line that has missing values where R can't place the information in the correct column.Then, I must tell R what to do when it finds multiple white space with white space as missing value together. It looks very tricky for me.

I checked the function read.fwf(), but I'm not sure how it can help me to sort my problem out.

Thank you

Luan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The width argument can be used to specify the column width in `read.fwf`

```
read.fwf("http://weather.uwyo.edu/cgi-bin/sounding?region=samer&TYPE=TEXT:LIST&YEAR=2016&MONTH=02&FROM=1212&TO=1212&STNM=83746",
width=rep(7, 11), skip=10,n=84)
```

and `n` sets the maximum number of rows to read in

Comment: It worked very well, thank you. How did you find out the number 7?

Comment: I looked at the data file you linked to and saw that each column was exactly 7 characters wide.Very low-tech and included a bit of finger counting :)  Please accept the answer if it solves/answers your question.

Comment: thanks again! I thought they could have different characters wide

Comment: They are allowed to have different widths. Then you would just need to specify the individual widths as the width vector: `c(7, 8, 11, 4, 7, 10, 7, 7)`