# Why in R string entries do not get read into the data.frame?

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

I have a `data.tsv` file (tabs separate entries). The full file can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1s2AelZ6MYdX4-RRmgPLJPlKrwUN2pEK2/view?usp=sharing).

The entries in the file look like this:

```
">173D:C"   "TVPGVXTVPGV"   "CCSCCCCCCCC"
">173D:D"   "TVPGVXTVPGV"   "CCCCCCCCSCC"
">185D:A"   "SAXVSAXV"  "CCBCCCBC"
">1A0M:B"   "GCCSDPRCNMNNPDYCX" "CCTTSHHHHHTCTTTCC"
">1A0M:A"   "GCCSDPRCNMNNPDYCX" "CGGGSHHHHHHCTTTCC"
">1A0N:A"   "PPRPLPVAPGSSKT"    "CCCCCCCCSTTCCC"
```

I am trying to read string entries into the data frame (into a matrix
containing 3 columns):

```
data = data.frame(read.csv(file = './data.tsv', header = FALSE, sep = '\t'))
```

but only the first column is read. All other columns are empty.

I also tried different commands, such as

```
data = read.csv(file = './data.tsv', header = FALSE, sep = '\t')
data = read.csv(file = './data.tsv', sep = '\t')
data = data.frame(read.csv(file = './data.tsv'))
```

but without success. Can someone foresee why the input does not get read
successfully?

Comment: You don't need the data frame, `read.csv` returns that already. Use `read.table` for tab separated data. Check that you really have tabs in your data, not multiple spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sep=''`

```
data = read.csv(file = './data.tsv', header = FALSE, sep = '')
```

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16979858/reading-text-file-with-multiple-space-as-delimiter-in-r).

Comment: `read.csv` produces a data.frame as its output.  there is no need for `data.frame()`

Comment: I tried this, but the result is the same, I also removed `data.frame()`

Comment: This works on my machine with the data you've given so I'm not sure how else to help. Maybe try G. Grothendieck's answer.

Comment: Actually your method works, just print(data) does not properly print the data, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Using the file defined reproducibly in the Note at the end this works:

```
DF <- read.table("myfile.dat", as.is = TRUE)
```

gives:

```
> DF
       V1                V2                V3
1 >173D:C       TVPGVXTVPGV       CCSCCCCCCCC
2 >173D:D       TVPGVXTVPGV       CCCCCCCCSCC
3 >185D:A          SAXVSAXV          CCBCCCBC
4 >1A0M:B GCCSDPRCNMNNPDYCX CCTTSHHHHHTCTTTCC
5 >1A0M:A GCCSDPRCNMNNPDYCX CGGGSHHHHHHCTTTCC
6 >1A0N:A    PPRPLPVAPGSSKT    CCCCCCCCSTTCCC
```

### Note

```
Lines <- '">173D:C"   "TVPGVXTVPGV"   "CCSCCCCCCCC"
">173D:D"   "TVPGVXTVPGV"   "CCCCCCCCSCC"
">185D:A"   "SAXVSAXV"  "CCBCCCBC"
">1A0M:B"   "GCCSDPRCNMNNPDYCX" "CCTTSHHHHHTCTTTCC"
">1A0M:A"   "GCCSDPRCNMNNPDYCX" "CGGGSHHHHHHCTTTCC"
">1A0N:A"   "PPRPLPVAPGSSKT"    "CCCCCCCCSTTCCC"'
writeLines(Lines, "myfile.dat")
```