# Unwanted character " âˆ’" appearing when importing text files

Tags: r, text-files

I have a notepad txt file called `inflation.txt`.

The file has two columns (delimited with a "space") and looks something like this:

```
1950-1 0.0084490544865279
1950-2 −0.0050487986543660
1950-3 0.0038461526886055
1950-4 0.0214293914558992
1951-1 0.0232839389540449
1951-2 0.0299121323429455
1951-3 0.0379293285389640
1951-4 0.0212773984472849
```

I am trying to import this file into R.

Reading this previous stackoverflow post over here [Reading text file with multiple space as delimiter in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16979858/reading-text-file-with-multiple-space-as-delimiter-in-r) , I adapted the code for my problem

```
data <- read.table("inflation.txt", sep = "" , header = F ,
                   na.strings ="", stringsAsFactors= F)
```

But when I run the above code, an unwanted character appears ( " âˆ’") :

```
> head(data)

      V1                    V2
1 1950-1    0.0084490544865279
2 1950-2 âˆ’0.0050487986543660
3 1950-3    0.0038461526886055
4 1950-4    0.0214293914558992
5 1951-1    0.0232839389540449
6 1951-2    0.0299121323429455
```

Can someone please show me what I am doing wrong? Is the data getting corrupted? Is there a way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

What do you get if you try this

```
data <- read.table("inflation.txt", sep = "" , header = F ,
                   na.strings ="", stringsAsFactors= F, encoding = "UTF-8")
```

That weird character looks like a utf-8 symbol

Comment: This works! Can you please explain your logic? Why was this character coming?

Comment: Waldi gave a great answer with the reason.

Comment: I looking at the R file created by your answer... all negative values are replaced with NA's. Do you know how to fix this? Thank you

Comment: here is what i mean: data <- read.table("inflation.txt", sep = "" , header = F ,
                   na.strings ="", stringsAsFactors= F, encoding = "UTF-8") ; b=as.numeric(data$V2) ;  b=as.numeric(data$V2) ;

Comment: > head(b)
0.008449054          NA 0.003846153 0.021429391 0.023283939 0.029912132

Comment: do you know why the "NA" is appearing here?

Answer (score 1):

The minus sign in the file isn't `-` , it's `−`.
You can compare the character code using this [link](http://www.mauvecloud.net/charsets/CharCodeFinder.html).
In the case of `-`, you get `ASCII 45` which corresponds to `unicode 002D`, and with the character above you get `8722` which correponds to `unicode 2212`.
Both are `minus` sign, but `read.table` expects the first version.

You could replace the wrong characters sequence :

```
file <- readLines('inflation.txt')
file <- gsub( "âˆ’", "-", file )

data <- read.table(textConnection(file), sep = "" , header = F ,
           na.strings ="", stringsAsFactors= F)

head(data) 
      V1           V2
1 1950-1  0.008449054
2 1950-2 -0.005048799
3 1950-3  0.003846153
4 1950-4  0.021429391
5 1951-1  0.023283939
6 1951-2  0.029912132
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried the answer above and all negative values are replaced with NA. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: thank you for your reply. I tried to convert the "V2" column as a "numeric" but it does not seem to be working. I posted a related question over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66299281/r-na-introduced-by-coercion . Can you please take a look at it if you have time? Thank you for all your help - I really appreciate it,

Comment: @Noob, on my  computer, `class(data$V2)` is `numeric`. You could try the `dec='.'` argument in `read.table`